# Job offer decline after verbal "acceptance"

Tags: job-offer, ethics

I recently received a job offer from A, my second choice, via email but had a final interview scheduled with B, my first choice, a few days later. I gave a verbal acceptance to A (although it was not my intention to do so. I felt that saying "I need more time" and the like was not a good idea, especially since I didn't have definite options at hand). A sent my name to HR to background check and asked for a potential start date and I responded accordingly (which was a mistake... should have asked for more time at this point).

But, during my B interview, I was offered the job at the end of the meeting (probably because I told them I already had job offer from A on the table).

I feel that I have the right to take B's offer, since the background check for A is not completed and did not sign anything (though, these jobs do not necessarily need a signature),  but am in an awkward situation to settle with A. I am afraid of an unpleasant response, especially because I feel very grateful for the job offer, the first one in months. How should I handle this?

Comment: Not sure if I follow 100%. It means your situation now is - you have offer for job B which is good but not best, OR you can *maybe* take job in some weeks/months at company A which you feel is best?

Comment: Please edit you question. We need to reread parts because you talk about *second company*, and then about *second offer*, which actually is *first company*. Just name them A and B.

Comment: Are these offers in writing?

Answer (score 6):

There's nothing wrong with saying "I need more time" if that's what you need.  It's perfectly acceptable to say "thank you for the offer, I need to take some time to think it over and discuss it with my significant other, and I'll let you know what I decide as soon as possible".  Perfectly acceptable, and certainly less complicated than accepting the offer and then changing your mind a short time later.  And it can also help from a negotiation standpoint if you make it clear that you've got another offer that you're considering.

That said, yes, you're fully entitled to accept the second offer (regardless of your background check status, and generally regardless of any employment contract you might sign; unless you sign one with a particularly harsh non-compete clause in it, though harsh non-compete clauses are often not enforceable).  And yes, it will likely be fairly awkward dealing with the first company.

> How should I handle this?

Just be honest, and apologetic.

Tell them that you're sorry for what's happened, but that shortly after you accepted their offer (and don't beat around the bush on that point; just admit to having accepted the offer) you received another offer from a different company that was too good to pass up, so unfortunately you have no choice but to rescind your acceptance as you can't work two jobs at once.  Thank them for their time, and apologize once more, and that should be it.

They may or may not take it in stride, but as long as you're polite, apologetic, and honest that's about as much as you can do on your end.  If they're a larger company, they've probably had this happen at least a few times in the past and won't be particularly irked by the situation.

Comment: Also, understand that you may not be able to avoid an unpleasant response from them. They have likely already contacted all their other applicants to say sorry, we have given the job to someone else, and now they have to go back and say, "Congratulations! You are our second choice." I think you should be prepared for this to be really uncomfortable and understand that you are burning bridges in your industry.

Answer (score 1):

This is a delicate situation.

By turning down the verbally accepted offer, you are risking to burn bridges. The consequences of burning that bridge would depend on your location, your industry, etc. For example, in my industry, it is not uncommon to come across a candidate that you had done business with in one form or another ten years prior.

However, first and foremost, you have to think about your long term career and what is best for you in the long run. If the second offer is best for you, I would decline the first. Your task then is to minimize the consequences. I would say something like the following to the first company:

> I am really sorry to have to do that but as explained during the interview process, I received an offer from another company and for reason X, Y, it is better for me long run to go there. I sincerely apologize as I know how much time you invested in the hiring process...

By the way, it is also possible, at least in some states of the USA, to declined a signed job offer. This is equivalent to a resignation and of course there are also the associated consequences.

Comment: I'd imagine that it's generally possible in the vast majority of locales to rescind an accepted offer no matter how it was accepted.  As you note, at worst it's essentially equivalent to a resignation.

Comment: I am guessing that it some locales, you may have to give notice or more painfully obtain an infamous relieving letter if you have signed an offer. I am not sure.